# input tag type=text works as link

Tags: html, input, hyperlink

I want to know, if input type=text can work as link. I need to add rel attribute to the tag, if it's possible. Now what I am doing is put an empty *a* tag exactly above the input, it works fine, but I also need to write on the input tag. Because of the a tag (it has the same size with the input tag) I can't write on the input tag anymore.
Anyone can help? Thanks

Comment: In what way do you want it to 'work as link'? On click it should load a new page, or do something else? (Note that it can be made to do so, with JavaScript, but not with just plain HTML/CSS; nor would I advise you to do so with JavaScript, but that's perhaps only because I don't know your use-case, and it just *seems* like a bad UI feature.)

Comment: i think you need something like jQuery tagit plugin...http://webspirited.com/tagit/

Comment: @david Thomas: I wanna add rel attribute to trigger jQuery overlay plugin. Thanks for your response